# How to view multiple versions of a column - HBASE HIVE Integration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have created a external hive table that points on top of a HBASE table. I understand HBASE stores multiple versions of a column.

My understanding is that the hive query on HBASE will fetch the latest version from the HBASE for a column.

Is there a way i can mention the version of a column to be retrieved either (VERSIONS or TIMERANGE hbase clause) ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Hive HBase integration documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration):

> There is currently no way to access the HBase timestamp attribute, and queries always access data with the latest timestamp.

So no, sorry, it doesn't look like there is currently an easy way to do this. It looks like you might have to write your own custom InputFormat and/or SerDe to accomplish it.